# ImageView switching drawable takes very long

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I'm trying to make a toggleable on/off button using an `ImageView` but the image is taking forever to change.

Here's my code:

```
public void toggleBtn(View v) {
    ImageView btn = (ImageView) v;
    if (state) { // "state" is a variable that switches with the button
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pwbtn_off));
        state = !state;
    } else {
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pwbtn_on));
        state = !state;
    }
}
```

The code after the image change runs before the image changes (I'm assuming the change is async) but both the images are just **52KB** so I doubt it's taking so long to load the images.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: First, start by defining "forever" because I don't think that is meant literally here or it would be a different question.

Comment: Good point. I changed the title

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) the view to force the OS to update the layout.

```
public void toggleBtn(View v) {
    ImageView btn = (ImageView) v;
    if (state) { // "state" is a variable that switches with the button
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pwbtn_off));
        state = !state;
    } else {
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pwbtn_on));
        state = !state;
    }
    v.invalidate();

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything but I'll try to test it on some other devices just to be sure

Comment: You may also need to add v.requestLayout()

Comment: I tried that already and I just tried both of these at once and it's still not helping (tested on 2.2, 4.2 and 4.4)